# SMS/ Email notification in iOS objective C

Tags: ios, email, notifications, sms, alert

How do I send notifications via SMS or Email to users? The server side is done in PHP using Drupal framework. I know how the push notification works. But I do not have an idea on the SMS and Email notification.

I do not know from where to start. I browsed but I did not understand what to follow as I am not very much experienced in app development.

Comment: You can try Twilio services. https://www.twilio.com/

Comment: You need to get a sms gateway to send sms. there are many companies which provide the gateway and their api. For Email's you can prepare a api in your server and make it to send the emails whenever api is hitted by your app.

Comment: Ok.. So for email also should I use gateway? Are all paid services? Is there something which is free and can be used instantly for testing purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following scenario:

Implement Web Service which contains code for sms gateway or email service. Make a call to Web Service when you wants to send sms or email.

Comment: Ok.. So for email also should I use gateway? Are all paid services? Is there something which is free and can be used instantly for testing purpose?

Comment: use twilio for testing purpose